# Splitting a Iris (.data file) into a list of lists

Tags: python, list, function

I'm pretty new at programming so I'll apologize in advance if this question is too easy but I've looked everywhere on the internet and I am stil not getting it.

I want to work with a Iris and I obviously need to split it first.

```
def ri(filename):
    linelist=list()
    with open (filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            linelist.append(line)
            return linelist
data=ri("iris.data")
print(data)
```

This was my first take on it but the problem I'm having is that this code gives me a string but I need a list of the datapoints. 1 Example of the Iris is 5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,Iris-setosa but it needs to look like this = [[5.7],[3.8],[1.7],[0.3],[1]].

I googled everything but I can't find anything.

Thanks in advance

Edit: The file looks like this

5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa

4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa

5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa

4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa

5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa

And my working code is this: but obviously not what I want it to do

```
def read_iris(filename):    
    f=open("iris.data", "r")
        if f.mode == 'r':
            x =f.readlines()
        return x
data = read_iris("iris.data")
print(data)

>> ['5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n', '4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n', '4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa\n', '4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa\n', '5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa\n', '5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa\n', '4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa\n', '5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa\n',
```

Comment: Do you mind to share with us a [mcve](/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hey RandomDog! While it is definitely valuable to learn how to read data in like this, I recommend checking out this package called Pandas (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) - it is great for working with tables

Comment: I assume you are trying to get into machine learning, I would also recommend learning the basic of pandas/dataframe, working with list of lists in ML can be very tedious and problematic.

Comment: Thanks for the answers I edited my Question for rpanai so you have more insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve your wanted results you can use this script:

```
def ri(filename):
    linelist=list()
    with open (filename) as f:
        for line in f:
            row_list = list()
            for element in line.split(','):
                element_list = list()
                if element.isalpha():
                    element_list.append(element)
                    row_list.append(element_list)
                else:
                    element_list.append(float(element))
                    row_list.append(element_list)
            linelist.append(row_list)
    return linelist

data=ri("iris.data")
print(data)
```

Comment: Running your code gives me following Error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Iris-setosa\n'

Comment: 10                     row_list.append(element_list)
     11                 else:
---> 12                     element_list.append(float(element))

Comment: I modified and worked with your code and got it. Thanks a lot  @everyone who helped me

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `pandas`? If you work with tabular data there is no point to do it by hands.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("iris.data", header=None)

print(df[df.columns[:-1]].values)

[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]
 [5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4]
 [4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3]
 [5.  3.4 1.5 0.2]]
```